# Can I listen on a port without interrupting traffic?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have developed the bare bones on a socket server in Python. I'm trying to capture the HTTP packets going to a web server without blocking them.

```
    try:
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', configuration.get('port')))
    except OSError as OE:
        logging.report("That port appears to be in use.")
```

The problem is, the machine I'm running it has a webserver bound on 80.

Is it possible to listen on a port without blocking other applications or interfering with them?

Comment: It's possible, but not by using regular sockets. You need a packet capture tool for your platform (you haven't said what it is, but look at wireshark).

Comment: The alternative is to code a forwarding proxy, which is essentially a man-in-the-middle, but that hardly counts as not interfering.

Comment: If you just want to do a packet capture, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can do that.  It's also open source (GPLv2) so you might be able to figure out how it does it. (It's [not written in python](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChIntroDevelopment.html) though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality for that is located in the [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) API. The implementation of that is in library libpcap for Unix/Linux and library Winpcap for Windows.

There are Python wrappers, e.g. [pypcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap), to access those libraries.

Depending on your system, you might need 'elevated privileges' (root/administrator) to gain access to packet data.

Wireshark is built on top of these libraries.